# Commands in the Azure ML yml files

Tags: yaml, command-line-interface, azure-machine-learning-service

When reading the examples from Microsoft on azure ML CLI v2, they use the symbols:
"|", ">", etc., in their yml files.

What do they mean, and where can I find explanations of possible syntax for the Azure CLI v2 engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| - This pipe symbol in YAML document is used for ***"Multiple line statements"***

```
description: |
  # Azure Machine Learning "hello world" job

  This is a "hello world" job running in the cloud via Azure Machine Learning!

  ## Description

  Markdown is supported in the studio for job descriptions! You can edit the description there or via CLI.
```

in the above example, we need to write some multiple line description. So, we need to use "|" symbol

">" - This symbol is used to save some content directly to a specific location document.

```
command: echo "hello world" > ./outputs/helloworld.txt
```

In this above command, we need to post **"hello world"** to ***"helloworld.txt"***

Check the below link for complete documentation regarding YAML files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-job-command

All these symbols are the YAML job commands which are used to accomplish a specific task through CLI.